# get distinct values from all totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

i've got this table structure:

```
Make    Model   Year    Sales
Toyota  Corolla 2014    15
Toyota  CAMRY   2014    12
Toyota  Camry   2015    7
Toyota  COROLLA 2015    5
Toyota  RAV4    2014    4
Toyota  RAV4    2015    2
```

I want to get distinct, only vehicles with highest sales
so only like this:

```
Make    Model   Year    Sales
Toyota  Corolla 2014    15
Toyota  Camry   2014    12
Toyota  RAV4    2014    4
```

Comment: Any reason for `Year` 2015 for camry. Even that should be 2014 right?

Answer (score 0):

Give a `row_number` partition by `Make` and `Model` and `order by` sales in descending order.
Then select the rows which `rn = 1`.

```
;with cte as
(
    select rn=row_number() over
    (
        partition by Make,Model
        order by sales desc
    ),*
    from sales
) 
select Make,Model,[Year],Sales 
from cte
where rn = 1
order by Sales desc;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d898/1)

Comment: This is misleading. With the lack of description of what you have done it implies that the solution is somehow related to a CTE. This can be achieved using a subquery, and the key point to mention is the use of `ROW_NUMBER()` not the use of a CTE. It is why I think all good answers come with an explanation, even if it is only a sentence or two. Also, based on the desired output I don't think `[Year]` should be included in the partition.